# How to use Selenium to get frame

Tags: java, selenium

I use Selenium to get this page

```
...
<frameset rows="0,0,*" frameborder="no" border="0">
    <frame name="applet_container" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" noresize src="">
    <frame name="javascript_container" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" noresize src="js.do">
    <frame name="main" scrolling="yes" noresize src="Loading.do" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0">
</frameset>
...
```

In javascript_container, there is a function to replace main

```
...
function replaceMainPage()
{
    parent.frames["main"].document.location.href = "/XXXForm.do";
}

function formOnLoad()
{
    setTimeout("replaceMainPage()", 500);
}

</script>
</head>

<body onLoad="formOnLoad()" BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF">
javascript container
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to use this to switch the frame

```
driver.switchTo().frame("main");
String main=driver.getPageSource();
```

But the content is still Loading.do, not XXXForm.do

How to get the correct html for this frame?

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.name("javascript_container"));
String main=driver.getPageSource();
```

Comment: I need main frame, do you mean `driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.name("main"));`? I just tried, and got same result